# Splitting file with contains similar lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file that contains information related to many interfaces. My example only has two for simplicity.

I need to be able to split this up into different variables which I intend to use later. For example, from the text below I'd like to create variables called eth1_ip that has a value of 10.196.135.30, eth1_mask with a variable of 255.0.0.0, eth2_ip with a value of 192.168.4.2 etc.

I've been going through different "split" and "readfiles" scenarios but haven't been able to nail this down.

I'm new to python and any tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
eth1:  
     Flags: (0x1043) UP BROADCAST MULTICAST TRAILERS ARP RUNNING   
     Type: GIGABIT_ETHERNET  
     inet is: 10.196.135.30 Vlan: 0  
     Netmask: 255.0.0.0  
     Ethernet address is 00:08:25:21:f8:a0  
     Metric is 0:  
     Maximum Transfer Unit size is 1500    

eth2:  
     Flags: (0x1003) UP BROADCAST MULTICAST TRAILERS ARP   
     Type: UNKNOWN_TYPE  
     inet is: 192.168.4.2 Vlan: 0  
     Ethernet address is 00:08:25:21:f8:a1  
     Metric is 0:  
     Maximum Transfer Unit size is 1500
```

My first attempt included ideas such as this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re, os, sys, fnmatch
import telnetlib
import sys
import time
import difflib
import shutil


def gleen_macs():
    text = open('show_interfaces.txt', 'r')
    for line in text.readlines():
        #print line   
        if re.match('(     Ethernet address)(.*)', line):
            values = line.split('is')
            print values[1]

def menu():
    get_macs()

menu()
```

I was concentrating on the mac first. I can split them but can't assign them to a variable as I wish. (The "get_macs()" function is just the telnetlib bit I used to generate the file. This is working as I wish and not included here).

Comment: Can you post your first attempt at this problem?

Comment: An open file is an iterable of strings.  For development, put your 'iterable of strings' in the code.  `file = """eth1: <remained of lines, with newlines>""".splitlines()`.  `file is now a list (an iterable) of strings.  Any code posted with `file` can be copied and tested on other computers. Now proceed.

Comment: Is the file structure exactly like you have shown for all *records*?

Comment: "Is the file structure exactly like you have shown for all records?" Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just step through the file, look for keywords in each line, if a line has something you need extract it, save in a dictionary,

```
results = dict()
with open('eth.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith(':') and not line.startswith('Metric'):
            eth = line[:-1]
        elif line.startswith('inet'):
            line = line.split(':')
            ip, _ = line[1].split()
            results[eth + '_ip'] = ip
        elif line.startswith('Netmask'):
            _, mask = line.split(':')
            mask = mask.strip()
            results[eth + '_mask'] = mask

>>> results
{'eth2_ip': '192.168.4.2', 'eth1_ip': '10.196.135.30', 'eth1_mask': '255.0.0.0'}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer WWII.

Comment: @user3183485, is it close to what you need?

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('interfaces.txt') as infile:
    # Each interface must be separated by a blank line as in the sample
    interfaces = infile.read().split('\n\n')

interfaces = map(str.splitlines, interfaces)
interfaces = {lines[0][:-1]: [line.strip() for line in lines[1:]]
              for lines in interfaces}


def interface_value(interface_name, line_prefix):
    # Make this argument case-insensitive to make the function easier to use
    line_prefix = line_prefix.lower()
    lines = [line for line in interfaces[interface_name]
             if line.lower().startswith(line_prefix)]
    if len(lines) == 0:
        raise ValueError('No lines found with given prefix')
    if len(lines) > 1:
        raise ValueError('Multiple lines found with given prefix: \n %s' % lines)
    return lines[0][len(line_prefix):].strip(': ')


eth1_flags = interface_value('eth1', 'flags')
eth2_mtu = interface_value('eth2', 'Maximum Transfer Unit size is')

print(eth1_flags)
print(eth2_mtu)
```

Output:

```
(0x1043) UP BROADCAST MULTICAST TRAILERS ARP RUNNING
1500
```

I'll let you do additional parsing like getting the IP out of `"10.196.135.30 Vlan: 0"`.

Comment: That was fast Alex. Thank you. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Provide an explaination?

Comment: @ppperry that's a lot of code to explain. I'd much rather answer specific questions if anyone has any. Please don't downvote just because I haven't explained the code.

Comment: Alex, is there a typo in "interfaces = {lines[0][:-1]: [line.strip() for line in lines[1:]] for lines in interfaces}"? I get a syntax error for the second "for".

Comment: @user3183485 sounds like you're running Python 2.6. Try `dict((lines[0][:-1], [line.strip() for line in lines[1:]]) for lines in interfaces)`.